# GAE Python Datastore - query on nested class table

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Java class that contains some nested classes, as follow:

```
public class OuterClass{

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    // --- blah blah

    static class MyNestedClass{
        //--- properties declaration
    }
}
```

This class works fine, basically within just one structure (OuterClass) I can store *n* nested structures, and each structure works as a datastore table.

Inspecting my ds with `datastore viewer` I see that I have now a table called `OuterClass$MyNestedClass`, I can successfully run GQL queries on this table like this:

```
//--- note the wrapping quotation marks on the table name
SELECT * FROM "OuterClass$MyNestedClass" where something = '100'
```

Till now everything is OK. Now I need to create a `google app engine python` method that empties that nested class table. I already did this with other tables/classes, but never with nested classes.

This is my python code:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db

class OuterClass$MyNestedClass(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    surname= db.StringProperty()
    age = db.StringProperty()

class emptyMyNestedClassHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        nestedclass= db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM \"OuterClass$MyNestedClass\"")
        count = 0

        for p in nestedclass:
            count += 1
        db.delete(nestedclass)

        self.response.out.write("Deleted SMyNestedClass Entities: " + str(count))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/emptyMyNestedClass', emptyMyNestedClassHandler)
], debug=True)
```

and this is the error I'm getting

```
class OuterClass$MyNestedClass(db.Model):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to change the class name from `OuterClass$MyNestedClass` to `MyNestedClass`, but I get this error:

```
KindError: No implementation for kind 'OuterClass$MyNestedClass'
```

Which name do I have to assign to my python class in order to make it work? How can I handle the $ issue?

hope I've been clear enough, thank you

---

### Solution

Following [Matt's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26629206/1054151), my JAVA class now looks like this:

```
public class OuterClass{

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    // --- blah blah
    @PersistenceCapable( table="NestedClass")
    @Embedded
    static class NestedClass{
        //--- properties declaration
    }
}
```

And this is the Python code:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db

class NestedClass(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    surname = db.StringProperty()
    age = db.StringProperty()

class emptyNestedClassHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        nestedclass= db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM NestedClass")
        count = 0

        for p in nestedclass:
            count += 1
        db.delete(nestedclass)

        self.response.out.write("Deleted NestedClassEntities: " + str(count))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/emptyNestedClass', emptyNestedClassHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Note that I **had** to declare class `NestedClass`.

Thanks!

Comment: watch out for the terminology "sub-class" and "super-class" because in this particular case you are showing a "static nested class" and an "outer class" respectively.  That aside, have you tried annotating the nested class with @Persistent( name="SomethingWithoutADollarSign")?

Comment: @Matt you are right, thanks, question updated! No I haven't tried it yet, I'll try it asap. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this resource for [JDO annotations](http://db.apache.org/jdo/annotations.html).

you may want to annotate your class like this:

```
public class OuterClass{

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    // --- blah blah
    @PersistenceCapable( table="NestedClass")
    @Embedded
    static class NestedClass{
        //--- properties declaration
    }
}
```

With which from GQL you should be able to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM "OuterClass" where NestedClass.something = '100'
```

Comment: `The annotation @Persistent is disallowed for this location`. Reading the @Persistent documentation: `Annotation used to define the fields/properties to be persisted.` this means that @Persistend can't be used on the class or nested class itself, am I correct?

Comment: take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses#Embedded_Classes), it shows 2 ways to obtain the same result, one with a nested class and another using only annotations.

Comment: I'm trying your solution, I'll let you know, thanks. If everything works then I should be able to define the nested class like this `class NestedClass(db.Model):` in my py code, right?

Comment: well, actually, at that point, you interact with the `@Embedded` table through the `where` clause of the outer table, so you shouldn't need to create an ORM layer in Python for that particular table.

Comment: I had to declare that class, anyway with your solution everything now works like a charm. Thanks